# Checkbox not working in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, angular4-forms

I could add a dropdown using angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  template: `
    <select id="select" formControlName = "day"  >                                                
    <option *ngFor = "let g of dayList" [value] = "g"> {{g}} 
    </option>
    </select>                                                                                             
  `,
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/M88wFl?p=preview

But I am unable to add multiple check-boxes

Code below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  template: `
    Select days in a week :
    <td class="even" *ngFor="let item of dayList;let i = index">                                                       
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.check"  type="checkbox" checked="item.check" formControlName = "selectedDays" (change)="updateChkbxArray(n.id, $event.checked, 'selectedDays')" value="n.id" >  {{item}}                                                                                                       
  `,
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gyAj6W?p=preview

Could you help me in showing the checkbox collection ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bind with `ngModel` and `formControlName`, Take a look here

```
<input class="input" type="search" #agmSearch>
<p class="even" *ngFor="let item of dayList;let i = index">
<input  type="checkbox" checked="item.check" (change)="updateChkbxArray(item, $event.checked, 'selectedDays')" value="n.id" >  {{item}}
</p>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-dynamic?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: its working, but how i get comma seperated json object while posting the form?

Comment: You can customize your object in the `(chnage)` method

Comment: The cupdatechkbxarray will create array collection of selected values but without formControlName = "selectedDays" how i get the selected dropdown values?   

I want it like selectedDays: {'Mon',"Wed"}

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used the input element, can you include "FormsModule" from '@angular/forms' in the root module of your app and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for showing multi checkbox and how to get multi selection in component

//HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let address of addressList">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{address.id}}" name="{{address.email}}" (change) ="updateSelectedTimeslots($event)" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

//Conponent

```
countries: any[] = [];
updateSelectedTimeslots(event) {
    let this.countries: any[] = [];
    if (event.target.checked) {
        if (this.countries.indexOf((event.target.name)) < 0) { 
                this.countries.push(({'email':event.target.name}));
        }
    } else {
         for(let i = 0; i < this.countries.length; i++) {
            let country = this.countries[i];
            if(country.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.name.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                this.countries.splice(this.countries.indexOf(({'email':event.target.name})), 1);              
            } 
        }
    }
}
```